# Java Spring: proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS how is it possible that the same object has different attributes?

Tags: java, spring

Please take a look at the following code:

```
@Component
@Scope(value= ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class JdbcConnection {

    public JdbcConnection() {
        System.out.println("JDBC Connection");
    }
}


@Component
public class PersonDAO {
    @Autowired
    JdbcConnection jdbcConnection;

    public JdbcConnection getJdbcConnection() {
        return jdbcConnection;
    }

    public void setJdbcConnection(JdbcConnection jdbcConnection) {
        this.jdbcConnection = jdbcConnection;
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringIn5StepsApplication {

    private static org.slf4j.Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringIn5StepsApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(SpringIn5StepsApplication.class, args);
        PersonDAO personDao = applicationContext.getBean(PersonDAO.class);
        PersonDAO personDao2 = applicationContext.getBean(PersonDAO.class);

        LOGGER.info("{}", personDao);
        LOGGER.info("{}", personDao.getJdbcConnection());

        LOGGER.info("{}", personDao2);
        LOGGER.info("{}", personDao2.getJdbcConnection());
    }
}
```

When running the code we get in console:

> : com.spring.basics.springin5steps.scope.PersonDAO@352c1b98  :
>   com.spring.basics.springin5steps.scope.JdbcConnection@41005828  :
>   com.spring.basics.springin5steps.scope.PersonDAO@352c1b98  :
>   com.spring.basics.springin5steps.scope.JdbcConnection@60b4beb4

It means that personDao and personDao2 are basically the same object. If so, how is it possible that after getting the attribute jdbcConnection from the object personDao we get two different objects?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` and `ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE`.

So spring generates cglib based proxy and injects it into your `PersonDAO` class. 
That proxy on each method invocation uses the new `JdbcConnection` (because the scope is `prototype`) and delegates method call to it.

And when you print the `JdbcConnection` you implicitly call `toString()` which causes `new JdbcConnection()` creation the `toString()` method will be called on.

> If so, how is it possible that after getting the attribute jdbcConnection from the object personDao we get two different objects?

No, you got the same object, but the `toString()` method is invoked on different objects. Try this:

```
JdbcConnection connection1 = dao.getJdbcConnection();
JdbcConnection connection2 = dao.getJdbcConnection();
System.out.println("connection1 == connection2: " + (connection1 == connection2));
```

Output:

> connection1 == connection2: true

Comment: What are the objects that the method toString() is invoked on?

Comment: New instances of JdbcConnnection. Method invoked on proxy then proxy instantiates new JdbcConnection, invokes method on it and returns the result